# C# Change folder and start process in CMD, wait for it to finish

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I need to open an external process from my Windows Forms app. What's more, I need to do it several times during the app's run time. Basically, I'm executing a .exe file with arguments several times from the command prompt, however I need to change the folder to where the .exe is in order for it to work properly. 
So far, I'm opening the cmd like so:

```
 ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Then using the process.WriteLine to feed commands to the CMD.

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Awin.exe -X " + filePath + "/" + fileNumber + " ID=\"" + id + "\"");
```

And I need t do this for several fileNumber files. Also, I need to wait for the process started from the input to end before going on to the next one.
Is there a better way to do this, because I'm not getting good results from using process.WaitForExit

Comment: What do you mean *I'm not getting good results from using process.WaitForExit*? Does subscribing to the [`Process.Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event yeild  accurate/reliable/etc results?

Comment: I mean that after notifying that WaitForExit has completed, the Awin.exe called from cmd still keeps running, although WaitForExit registered it as finished.

Comment: And same result with Process.Exited event? Otherwise you could get the ProcessID of Awin.exe and when it exits continue to poll Processes checking if the ProcessID is infact still alive

Answer (score 0):

`ProcessStartInfo` class has a `WorkingDirectory` property.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = your_directory
(...)

//do your thing
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Arguments can be passed via the `Arguments` property

Comment: I've tried this, but I always get an Exception saying that the directory name is invalid. Should I use backslashes instead of slashes?

Comment: You can get the directory name right by experimenting with `Directory.Exists`.